# Matlab and maximum error

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-optimization

This is a part of my code. I am wondering why it says "Error in line 15 m = max(d, u,1)"? Thanks!

```
%Inputs:
% n = size
% A is a n x n matrix
% a = how much matrix A is wanted to be shifted
% kounttol is the number of iterations
% d is the first number needed to form matrix T
% u is the second number needed to form matrix T
% tol is the the tolerance for the residual, i.e. your iteration
% should stop once the number of iteration is smaller than kounttol
% e is the vector of eigenvalues of matrix A
% m is the number of iterations k actually done

function lam=shiftedqr(n ,a, kounttol, d, u)
tol = 0.1e-08;
m = max(d, u, 1);
T = (d*eye(n) + uN)/m;
A = T + T';
e = eig (A);
```

Comment: You are using the max function wrong. You should look up its [documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html). If you simply want the maximum value of $d$, $u$, and $1$ you could write `max([d,u,1])`.

Comment: Oh, I looked it up online, and it says if A is a vector, I can simply use                         max(A). Sorry for this sloppy mistake.

Comment: @Eff Sorry another quick question. I ran the code again, and it says there is an error in this line $T = (d*eye(n)+u*N)/m$. Do I need to define $I = eye(n)$ first? But I did that before, and it still doesn't work..

Comment: I don't know what $N$ is. It's not defined in your code. No, you don't have to define something first, it can all be done inline.

Comment: O! I should define it first!! Thanks!